# Circle individual item in list dependent on boolean

Tags: lists, conditionals

Is there a way to create an enumerated list which has an item that will be circled when toggling a boolean?

I'd like to use it for creating multiple-choice tests and the solution key.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have a MWE to start with?

Comment: Have you tried using the `exam` class to create multiple-choice tests?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty solution with the `pifont` package and `\ding{172}` etc, however, the size of the digits isn't the same!

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifcircle
\circletrue
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\def\ctext#1{%
  \ifcircle %
  \ding{\the\numexpr\value{#1}+171}%
  \else
  \arabic{#1}%
  \fi
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\ctext}{\@ctext}{Second}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\ctext*}]
\circlefalse
\item First  \circletrue
\item Anotherone

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**And a Ti*k*Z solution** (Baseline is not working so far)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifcircle
\circletrue
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\drawcircled}[2][0.25cm]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
    \coordinate [xshift=2mm,yshift=2mm] (A) (0,0);%
    \draw (A) circle[radius=#1];%
    \node (Q) at (A) {#2};%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\newcommand{\drawuncircled}[2][0.25cm]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \coordinate [xshift=2mm,yshift=-2mm] (B) (0,0);%
    \draw [white] (B) circle[radius=#1];%
    \node (B) at (B) {#2};%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\makeatletter
\def\ctext#1{%
  \bfseries%
  \ifcircle %
  \protect\drawcircled{\number\value{#1}}%
  \else
  \protect\drawuncircled{\number\value{#1}}%
  \fi
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\ctext}{\@ctext}{Foo}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\ctext*}]
\circlefalse%
\item First  \circletrue%
\item Anotherone
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\item E
\item F
\item G
\item H
\item I
\item J

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with `\textcircled{}`?

Answer (score 0):

I find the TeX-command \llap quite useful when writing something over something, or to put a mark in the margin. A solution for this case could be like the following code. The two commented lines are for replacing the \bigcirc with a Tikz circle. Length and such should be adjusted depending on the font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\def\Correct{\strut\llap{\Large$\bigcirc$\rule{4pt}{0pt}}}
% \usepackage{tikz}
% \def\Correct{\strut\llap{\raisebox{-5pt}{\tikz\draw[thick](0,0)circle(0.3);}\rule{2pt}{0pt}}}
%%%%%%% 
\begin{document}
1. Question?
\begin{enumerate}
\item Answer 1
\item\Correct Answer 2
\item Answer 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```